# Prove that counting measure is a measure

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I am using the book Measure, Integration and Real Analysis (Axler, 2020) to study about measure.

The author gives the definition of a measure:

> Suppose $X$ is a set and $S$ is a $\sigma$ algebra on $X$. A measure on ($X,S$) is a function $\mu: S \to [0; \infty]$ such that:
>
> $\mu(\emptyset) = 0$
> $\mu(\bigcup \limits_{k =1}^{\infty} E_k) = \sum \limits_{k=1}^{\infty} \mu(E_k)$

The author then gives an example of measure using counting measure (page 41):

> If $X$ is a set and $S$ is the $\sigma$ algebra of all subsets of $X$.  Then the function $\mu$ defined below is a measure on $(X,S)$
> $\mu(E) = n$ if $E$ is a finite set containing $n$ elements
> $\mu(E) = \infty$ if $E$ is not a finite set

I am trying to prove that $\mu$ is a measure, using the definition of the author.
The part of $\mu(\emptyset) = 0$ is obvious.

For the countable additivity part, I have no idea how to do it because as far as I know, there is no definition of algebraic operation ($+, -$) on the extended real number (i.e. on $[0, \infty]$) as stated in the book Analysis 1 (Terence Tao, page 135):

> One could also introduce other operations on the extended real number system, such as addition, multiplication, etc. However, this is somewhat dangerous as these operations will almost certainly fail to obey
> the familiar rules of algebra.
>
> For instance, to define addition it seems reasonable (given one’s intuitive notion of infinity) to set $+\infty + 5$ = $+ \infty$
> and $+\infty + 3 = +\infty$, but then this implies that $+\infty + 5 = +\infty + 3$ while $5 \neq 3$.
>
> So things like the cancellation law begin to break down once we try to operate involving infinity. To avoid these issues we shall simply not define any arithmetic operations on the extended real number
> system other than negation and order

I would like to have 2 questions:

1. Is it reasonable to define the range of the measure function $\mu$ is $[0, \infty]$ instead of $[0, \infty)$ when we don't have any concept of algebraic manipulation on the extended real number (i.e.we don't know how to do $\mu(A) + \mu(B)$ in the extended real number). Moreover, as for me, the thought that there is a set of measure $\infty$ sounds not so intuitive.
2. Any idea on how to prove the part countable additive of $\mu$ counting measure is a measure ?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sets of measure $+\infty$ are not at all unusual: even in $\Bbb R$ in the standard Lebesgue measure we must allow this for sets as $\{x \in \Bbb R\mid x > 1\}$ e.g. We have to keep in mind we can do addition and have an order, but we have no subtraction in $[0,+\infty]$. Measures are usually taken with values in $[0,+\infty]$, as in your definition. Addition is then no problem: If in a sum/series there are no terms $+\infty$, we take the usual sum in $\Bbb R$ (for a series $\sum_n a_n$ where all $a_n \ge 0$ we take the sum of the increasing sequence $\sum_{n=1}^m a_n, m \in \Bbb N$ in $[0,+\infty]$, which always exists) and otherwise the sum is simply $+\infty$.

If $E_n, n \in \Bbb N$ are pairiwse disjoint and one of the, say $E_m$, is infinite, then the sum $\sum_n \mu(E_n) = +\infty$ as one of its terms is, and $\bigcup_n E_n$ is infinite (because it conatins the infinite $E_m$) so both values agree.

If all $E_n$ are finite, then we have a sum of numbers $\ge 1$, so all partial sums $\sum_{n=1}^m$ obey that they're $\ge m$ and so their supremum in $[0, +\infty]$ is $+\infty$, while OTOH $\bigcup_n E_n$ is infinite as a disjoint union of finite sets. Again agreement. We can safely ignore $E_n = \emptyset$ terms because they contribute $0$'s to the sum and don't affect the union. (If the series would reduce to a finite sum then the addition rule is quite obvious, almost by definition of cardinal arithmetic).

Comment: Thanks for your response! I do not fully understand that when we have the supremum of the sequence of partial sum is $+\infty$ why does it imply that $\sum \limits_{k=1}^{\infty} \mu(E_k) = \infty$  (i.e. why supremum implies sum) ? Thanks for your help!

Comment: @InTheSearchForKnowledge The only upper bound for all partial sums is $+\infty$, so that is the only candidate for the supremum.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Actually i am wondering whether "$\sum \limits_{k=1}^{\infty} \mu(E_k) = \infty$" is equivalent to saying "that supremum of the sequence of partial sum is equal to $\infty$" ?

Comment: @InTheSearchForKnowledge yes, it is. The sums must be unbounded which is almost always.

Comment: So basically, the notation "= $\infty$" is not to say that there sequence "converges" to $\infty$ ? The notation of "=" in this case confuses me a little bit.

Comment: @InTheSearchForKnowledge why? The sequence of partial sums also converges to $+\infty$ in the order topology by the way. So the sum really is equal to $+\infty$ in all ways.

Comment: I think that when we say a series "is equal to L", we actually mean that the sequence of partial sums "converges" to L. And by "converges", we mean that for every $\delta \gt 0$ there exists a natural number $N$ such that $|S_n - L| \lt \delta$ for all $n \gt N$. In this case of $+\infty$, i think this definition of "converges" does not apply, so we can't say the series is "equal" to $+ \infty$. Please correct me if there is something wrong. Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: @InTheSearchForKnowledge you should use the general definition of convergence: for every neighbourhood $O$ of $L$ there is an $N$ such that for all $ n \ge N$ we have $S_n \in L$. And a basic neighbourhood of $+\infty$ has the form $(r, +\infty]$ for a real $ r > 0$.

Comment: Thanks for your response. It seems there is a hole in my knowledge and I want to read more about it and its motivation. Could you please give a key word on this topic of definition of convergence so that I can search on Google? (i can't search for anything related to your definition of convergence using "general definition of convergence"). Thank you very much!

Comment: @InTheSearchForKnowledge any topology book will do, try Munkres e.g.

Comment: By "topology", did you mean "point-set topology" ?

Comment: @InTheSearchForKnowledge or general topology.

Answer (score 3):

1. The structure on $[0, \infty]$ is that of a monoid, so you only have addition and an identity element $0$. When saying $\infty + 5 = \infty + 3$ implies $5 = 3$, we add $-\infty$ on both sides, but we do not assume we have inverses, so that is not a counter example here. You can check the axioms of a monoid to see that $([0, \infty], +, 0)$ is well defined with regular addition.
2. Hint: a countable union of disjoint, non-empty sets is always infinite.

Comment: Thanks for your help! So do you mean that the definition of $+$ does not cause any problem on $[0, \infty]$ and it only causes a problem when we are trying to define $+$ on $[-\infty, +\infty]$ ?

Comment: @InTheSearchForKnowledge Yes